# Why can capacitor act as voltage source and inductor as current source?

Tags: inductor, current-source

Why can capacitor act as voltage source and inductor as current source?don't explain this with a math formula,just use an easier method,thanks a lot!

Comment: There are millions of analogies for explaining inductive and capacitive elements on the web. Why do you need an extra one written exclusiveley for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does someone have a non-textbook analogy to explain elements of a circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193839/does-someone-have-a-non-textbook-analogy-to-explain-elements-of-a-circuit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another dodgy water analogy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOd6oH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Water tank and pipe analogies.*

- The capacitor is like a water tanks where charge is the equivalent of water.

  - The more water you put into the tank the higher the level will be in the tank and the higher the pressure at the outlet.
  - The more charge you put into the capacitor the higher will be the voltage.
  - The larger the surface area of the tank the more water will be required to raise the level and the pressure. The larger the surface area of a capacitor the more charge will be required to raise the voltage.
- The inductor can be thought of as a water pipe. The water current is analogous to the electrical current in an inductor.

  - The water current has moment of inertia. Turning on the flow on a full pipe will result in a gradual build up of speed as the pressure driving it overcomes the inertia of the water in the pipe. Turning off the water suddenly when large flows are involved can cause water hammer due to sudden rises in pressure.
  - The inductor has an inertia to changes in current. As in the case of the water pipe current builds up gradually when turned on. If turned off suddenly large voltages can result and this can damage components unless protection such as snubber diodes are added in.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuw7VS.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A resonant circuit.*

Here for the sake of the illustration I have split the capacitor in a parallel resonant circuit into two.

If we disturb the level in one of the water tanks water will flow from the tank with higher pressure to the one with lower pressure. The momentum of the water in the pipe will cause the water to continue to flow past the point of equilibrium and the second tank will end up higher than the first. The current will reverse direction and the water will oscillate back and forth gradually decaying due to resistance of the pipe.

Similarly with the RL circuit a disturbance will cause an oscillating current to flow back and forth until it is damped down by the various resistances in the circuit.

Again, this is a dodge analogy - but it may help.

> Why can capacitor act as voltage source and inductor as current source?

Because, in the short-term, the capacitor tends to try to keep the voltage across it a constant value. (The pressure from the water tank doesn't change instantly when you start to draw water from it.)

Similarly, the inductor tends to try to keep the current through it a constant value. (The water flow in the pipe doesn't like being changed instantly when you shut it off suddenly.)

Comment: can this also explain that if we turn on the circuit ,and the inductor has no current,the inductor act as a open circuit at that moment?

Comment: so,we can think that if we turn on  the circuit,at that moment,the inductor will be destroyed,so the inductor is designed to be an "open circuit" at that moment  if we turn on the circuit to avoid this situation?

Comment: (1) Almost, yes. The inductor resists sudden changes in current so if current is initially zero it looks for an instant like an infinite resistance. (2) If it hadn't got inductance it would be just a piece of wire. Whether or not it would pass a very large and damaging current would depend on the circuitry around it and the current limits imposed by that circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

### <sub>Capacitor analogy</sub>

A freely spinning flywheel acts like a constant speed source. If it’s a big flywheel and you put your hand against it, it takes a lot of effort to slow it down or even stop it. Consider that a flywheel in this analogy is like the voltage on a capacitor.

You can also liken a capacitor to an ideal battery; if the voltage drops then you can restore that voltage with charge.

---

### <sub>Inductor analogy</sub>

Consider a rubber rope attached to a load that you might drag across a floor against friction. You might set off at a constant pace and the rubber rope stretches against the friction of the load. After a little while you might have walked 10 metres but the friction load has only moved 5 metres.

If you then stopped moving, the rubber rope is still exerting a force on the friction load and it continues moving towards you until the force is spent and the rope has reduced to its unstretched length. The elasticity of the rubber rope is analogous to inductance and the force travelling through the rubber rope is analogous to current. The friction load in this example is analogous to a resistor. The distance moved is analogous to voltage.

Comment: But a flywheel is whater analogy of a intuctor not a capcitor. .

Comment: I can make a flywheel an analogy of a capacitor if I want. Don’t be so closed about this.